# Why aren't dynamic folders being generated for assets?

Tags: assets

I have a field 'Event Listing Image' set up as:

- Field Type: Asset
- Restrict uploads to single folder
- Upload location [Events]{slug}

There's an asset bucket Events:

- Local Folder
- File System Path: {fileSystemPath}/content/events/
- URL: /content/events/

The field is in a section named Events of type Channel.

The system folder /content/events/ exists and is writable.

If I edit an existing Entry in that channel, I can click upload in that field, but it errors every time with:

> Upload failed for test.jpg. The error message was: ”Error uploading the file: The folder “/Users/matt/Sites/bs_conwyarts/_bespoke/public/content/events/test-event/” does not exist.“

I know it doesn't, it's dynamic based on the entry slug. Why is Craft not creating the folder?

Irony: I have a field called Featured Image set up almost identically on a different Channel that does work:

Featured Image:

- Field Type: Asset
- Restrict uploads to single folder
- Upload location [Artists]{slug}

Asset bucket Artists:

- Local folder
- File System Path: {fileSystemPath}/content/artists/
- URL: /content/artists

UPDATE: looks like a bug. It works fine for new entries posted in the Events channel, it does not work for the existing entry in the Channel. I think I added the field in question *after* creating the first entry, so it looks like that might be the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to Craft Twitter support; needed to re-build the Asset Indexes; because I'd added that field after already creating an entry the asset index was stale and needed flushing.

1. Open Craft admin dashboard
2. Click *Settings*
3. Click *Update Asset Indexes*
4. Click *Go!*

This process scans through the list of assets in the database and ensures it matches what is in the file system and updates the database as needed.